# How to have a maintainable username blacklist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

My app is a social platform and I want to have the support-team being able to maintain a blacklist for nicknames. Therefore I have a model Blacklist that contains the different names.

Now I tried with the `validates_exclusion_of` to map these into the `in:` but it raises the following error,

> wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

```
validates_exclusion_of :nickname, in: -> { 
  where(Blacklist.select(:name).map(&:name).uniq.to_s)
}, message: "This nickname is not allowed"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the values to exclude within a lambda, it'll work as is if you pass just the Blacklist AR query result.

```
validates_exclusion_of :nickname,
                       in: Blacklist.select(:name).map(&:name).uniq.to_s,
                       message: 'This nickname is not allowed'
```

Notice, you can use the [ActiveRecord::Calculations#pluck](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) in order to get just the names from Blacklist, getting rid of the select and map combination, and use [ActiveRecord::QueryMethod#distinct](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-distinct) to get non-repeated values.

With that you don't need the `uniq` and `to_s` step. The last one, because the validation is waiting for an enumerable object, and you'd be passing a string.

Something like:

```
validates_exclusion_of :nickname,
                       in: Blacklist.distinct.pluck(:name),
                       message: 'This nickname is not allowed'
```

The `where` you're using on the validation won't work, as it's applying a WHERE statement without passing a column name to check, so you'll get an `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid`.

Comment: But what happens if a name is blacklisted *after* the model class is loaded?

Comment: Thanks, sometimes it's the most obvious solution you don't see.

And to answer for what happen after. There is a cronjob running once a day to find all violation that creates a report for the support team. Here is manual effort required.

Comment: But the problem is that `Blacklist.distinct.pluck(:name)` will be computed when the surrounding model class is loaded. So if the blacklist is changed, changes won't be reflected in the validation list until the model class is reloaded.